# Cual es el equivalente en asp.net de la funcion "Execute" de asp

Tags: asp.net, asp

Estoy migrando una pagina de asp a asp.net y me suelo encontrar con la este tipo de funciones

```
function realizar_calculosRteTesDin(nombreDin)
    Execute("sumaIngresosCorriente" & nombreDin & "=" & chr(34) & Calculos(cCalculo1) & chr(34)) 
end function
```

Es un simple ejemplo, las funciones suelen ser mas complejas, solo quiero saber como se traduciría la función Execute.

Comment: Revisa esta [respuesta en inglés](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8122801/4092887). Te sugiero además no migrar exactamente cada línea de código que encuentres a la nueva versión _en tu caso, de VB a C#_.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Entiendo que la funcion esta evaluando un string, lo mas cercano a esto en .net es usar [CodeDOM](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/y2k85ax6(v=vs.110).aspx) para ejecutar esa evaluacion

[Dynamic Source Code Generation and Compilation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/650ax5cx(v=vs.110).aspx)

aqui

[Funcion Eval(codigo a ejecutar as string)](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/es-ES/d12071da-c788-4491-8490-6432a1b88675/funcion-evalcodigo-a-ejecutar-as-string?forum=vbes)

se planteo el mismo tema, pero no existe un equivalente, es mas habria que ver que implementacion tiene ese metodo Execute() realiza para evaluar el string